# Ansible | How to construct a csv string from a dictionary

Tags: ansible

I have a dictionary like this

```
customers:
  abc:
    id: 1
    status: active
  def:
    id: 2
    status: inactive
  ghi:
    id: 3
    status: active
  jkl:
    id: 4
    status: active
```

What's the best way to construct a string like below of the active customers only?

```
abc,ghi,jkl
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    customers:
      abc:
        id: 1
        status: active
      def:
        id: 2
        status: inactive
      ghi:
        id: 3
        status: active
      jkl:
        id: 4
        status: active
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ customers | dictsort | selectattr('1.status','equalto','active') | map(attribute='0') | join(',') }}"
```

Comment: One more question, how can I also append a string (e.g. cust_) so the output looks like this?

```cust_abc,cust_ghi,cust_jkl
```

Comment: Add `map('regex_replace','^','cust_')` before `join`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you asked for, but I think this might add value to the question.

In my case, I needed to join a list of items using a space.

**defaults/main.yml**

```
---
backup_dev_strip:
  - "@stripped"
  - "@development"
```

**vars/main.yml**

```
---
backup_dev_strip_merged: "{{ backup_dev_strip | join(' ') }}"
```

**As a result**

```
TASK [... : debug] 
ok: [...] => {
    "backup_dev_strip_merged": "@stripped @development"
}
```